# entity framework ctp5 get unproxied entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-ctp5

EF CTP 5. I have a single instance where I would like to get the unproxied entity. I can't seem to find a way to do this. I don't want to disable proxy creation all together, just need it for this one query. Can anyone help?

Here is a simple example:

```
var myEntity = DbContext.Entities.Find(1);
var unproxy = myEntity...?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the only possibility is to create new instance of `DbContext` and turn proxy creation off just to execute this query. The reason is that DynamicProxy is type created in runtime which derives from your original entity type and adds tracking and lazy loading functionality. You can't strip the proxy away once you created it this way. Try this:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext(connectionString))
{
  ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
  var myEntity = context.Entities.Find(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. Not optimal, and could be a PITA. Issue is I am trying to cache this, and if I cache proxy then it retains ChangeTracker and causes all types of issues.

Comment: If the only problem is with ChangeTracker you can try to run the query with .AsNoTracking() (and possibly also turn off lazy loading).

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.Net Core you can use [AsNoTracking()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#no-tracking-queries).

Eg:

```cs
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
```

More info you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/).