# Entity Framework 6.1.1 ignores ProxyCreationEnabled settings

Tags: c#, entity-framework, table-per-hierarchy

I have a context class, and at some point I need to get data from database in my POCO classes, so that I can serialize that data and send over to my web service. I do not want to deserialize proxies on the other end, but I am not able to force EF to create my POCO classes.

I am using following code to retrieve data:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
var nodes = (from node in TreeNodes select node).ToList();
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
```

Note that TreeNodes is a TPH and base class is abstract. Is there a way to get POCO classes in my case?

Comment: I guess this would happen if you already have some proxies loaded. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5015424/242520

Comment: Do you mean that ProxyCreationEnabled setting is ignored after first query is run?

Comment: I mean that for entities already loaded as proxies ... they are already loaded. So you get the entities loaded as proxies.

Comment: Now I think I got you. Well, seems like I have to rceate another instance of context for such an operation then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this scenario by instantiating same context again, settings configuration, and then run the query and disposing context.